# HTML link trailing slash

Tags: html

The [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp) documentation says:

> Without a trailing slash on subfolder addresses, you might generate two requests to the server. Many servers will automatically add a trailing slash to the address, and then create a new request.

It is not clear what exactly this means. What difference does it make to add a trailing slash in the href urls, is there a best practice regarding adding a trailing slash.

Comment: Surprised this question doesn't have lots more activity, I suppose because it was thought to be  a duplicate.

Comment: This is actually not a duplicate question because the other question was asked in 2016. I am not sure why this question is marked as duplicate.

Comment: When considering duplicates, age is --generally -- of no real importance, especially not if both questions are similarly received.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are two different URLs:

```
http://example.com/foo
http://example.com/foo/
```

Often, but not always, requesting the first URL will trigger the server to reply with a `301 Permanent Redirect` to the second URL. The browser will then have to make a second request to the second URL.

This is most commonly the case when the URL is mapped on to a directory on the server's file system and the `index.html` (or other directory index) is being loaded.

Servers where the content is being dynamically generated (e.g. with an MVC framework like Perl's Catalyst) are less likely to do this. In that case you often have to be even more careful with where you link to because relative URLs will resolve differently from the two URLs.

Comment: So the server decides whether to return 301 or not, so what difference it will make if we add a trailing space?

Comment: If you include the trailing slash, then you just go to the second URL. You don't try to get the first URL. You don't get told that you should have got the second URL. You save yourself a request and a response.

Answer (score 2):

Fundamentally, `http://example.com/foo` and `http://example.com/foo/` are two entirely different URLs. Ultimately what's important is how the server serving those URLs will respond when queried for those URLs. And it's entirely up to the server what to do. `.../foo` may return a file while `.../foo/` may return a directory listing. Or both may return a directory listing. Or a file. Or the same file. Or a random new response each and every time.

What W3S is pointing out is that *many* servers are *by default* configured to return a *redirect* response to the canonical version ending in a slash. Meaning, if you're requesting `.../foo` from that server, it will redirect you to `.../foo/`, which then causes your client to do a second request to `.../foo/`. Why or how or when a server may issue this redirect is entirely up to each server, and whether it's really such a popular practice is questionable (as is everything by W3S).

The important thing is that you point your URLs where you mean to point them. Is `.../foo` the correct URL because it's a file? Or is `.../foo/` the correct URL because it's the root of a (virtual) directory? You decide, you make sure your server behaves appropriately.

Comment: Since this is a part of HTML documentation, one generally thinks that it causes some difference in the browser behaviour.

Comment: Basically the browser treats ../foo/ and ../foo as two different URLs, and the server may or may not.

Comment: Exactly. There's also a subtle difference in *relative URLs* with those. `bar` relative to `.../foo` is `.../bar`; `bar` relative to `.../foo/` is `.../foo/bar`. That's browser-side logic.