# What's the actual meaning of 'two requests to the server' in this context?

Tags: html, url, hyperlink, httprequest

While studying HTML tutorial on [HTML Links Chapter](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp) on w3schools.com I saw following sentence:

> Without a forward slash on subfolder addresses, you might generate two requests to the server. Many servers will automatically add a forward slash to the address, and then create a new request.

I didn't get the meaning of how two request can be passed if trailing slash is missing in the URL mentioned in href attribute of anchor tag?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML link trailing slash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32184812/html-link-trailing-slash)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A web server receiving a request for `/foo` may look at it and see that its `foo` is actually a folder, and decide that the *actual* address for this folder is `/foo/`. So it will respond with a `302` redirect to the client and tell it to fetch `/foo/` instead:

1. browser to server: `GET /foo`
2. server to browser: `302 Found, Location: /foo/`
3. browser to server: `GET /foo/`
4. server to browser: `200 OK, content...`

Whether the server does this or not depends on your server. Ultimately you should always use the *actual URL* of items in your links, don't rely on a server to "fix it" implicitly for you.

Answer (score 8):

Consider you have a URL like this:

```
http://example.com/myfolder/
```

Since in many servers, the `directory` can be accessed without a trailing slash, but it is good to have one, right? So, the server, generally redirects the client to put the slash in the end.

**Why two requests?**

See the below conversation between the client and server.

1. **Client Request #1:** I am requesting you `http://example.com/myfolder`.
2. **Server Response #1:** I want you to go to `http://example.com/myfolder/`, `HTTP 302 Found` - This is a temporary redirect.
3. **Client Request #2:** Ah, OKay! I am requesting you `http://example.com/myfolder/`.
4. **Server Response #2:** Sure, here you go. `HTTP 200 OK` - Here's your content.

So there are two requests from the client to the server. Hope you understand.

<sub>*ps: Please do not use W3Schools, there are lot more better resources.*</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your answer but tell me what's wrong in using W3Schools tutorials.  Whatever I searched on internet for learning HTML W3Schools is the only best tutorial I found which is at its best in simplicity and lucidity. Then why you are against W3schools?

Comment: @user2839497 It had its image damaged to the extent that no developers will recommend the newbies. I agree W3Schools was once upon a time, the best resource, but they haven't updated much. See more information at http://w3fools.com. `:)`

Comment: You could check the tutorials on w3schools. They are updated and being continuously updated to match up to the current web trends and web standards. w3fools is a old community and they keep on targeting w3schools since long time. You might be unaware of the fact that w3schools accepted the criticism from w3fools and made the necessary improvements in their web tutorials. So, I kindly request you don't make nagative publicity of w3schools.com please.

Comment: @user2839497 Agreed and thanks. `:)` I will have a review to it, and from right now will stop saying negative about W3Schools. `:)`

Comment: Thanks you so much Praveen for the spirit you shown. It's only our responsibility to avoid stop spreading wrong words about something which may divert newbies in the web world.

Comment: @user2839497 Dude, that's trailing slash - which means, the last slash.